# Hilt Create one view model instance shared between the activity and their fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Iam trying to create shared view model between activity and the fragments.
In the activity :

```
    val viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
```

And in fragments:

```
val viewModel: SharedViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.activity_nav_graph) {
        defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    }
```

But 2 instances currently created one on the activity and one in the fragments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your fragment should be

```
private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```